# Combine these two lists into one

Tags: python, list

There are 2 lists. You need to combine these list items into one. So that the elements of the first match the values of the second and vice versa, the second=the first. But there is one thing, if there is an element in the second list that contains an underscore at the end, then you need to consider it correct and save the choice from the first list (without the underscore).

```
lst1 = ['NAME', 'SURNAME', 'AGE', 'ID']
lst2 = [['NAME', 'JOHN'], ['SURNAME', 'SMITH'], ['ACTIVE', 'Y'], ['ID_', '33']]
```

It should turn out like this

```
lst3 = [['NAME', 'JOHN'], ['SURNAME', 'SMITH'], ['ID', '33']]
```

I wrote such a variant, but it collects a complete match, which excludes elements with underscores. Is there any simple option not to exclude such elements when filtering.

```
lst3= sorted(filter(lambda x: x[0] in lst1, lst2),
                     key=lambda x: lst1.index(x[0]))
```

Comment: `lst3 = [elem from lst2 if elem[0] in list1 or (elem[0][-1] == '_' and elem[0][:-1]) in list1]` should work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a temporary dictionary for mapping:

```py
lst1 = ["NAME", "SURNAME", "AGE", "ID"]
lst2 = [["NAME", "JOHN"], ["SURNAME", "SMITH"], ["ACTIVE", "Y"], ["ID_", "33"]]

tmp = {k.rstrip("_"): v for k, v in lst2}
out = [[k, tmp[k]] for k in lst1 if k in tmp]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[['NAME', 'JOHN'], ['SURNAME', 'SMITH'], ['ID', '33']]
```

Comment: You can combine these steps without getting too golfie: `out = [ [k.strip("_"), v] for k, v in lst2 if k.strip("_") in lst1 ]`

Comment: Thanks! It will work with the current data. But if lst2 has two underscores, and lst1 has one `lst1 = ["ID"]` `lst2 = [["ID__", "33"]]` it should be like this `[['NAME', 'JOHN'], ['SURNAME', 'SMITH'], ['ID_', '33']]` - only the last character should be taken

Answer (score 1):

```
lst1 = ['NAME', 'SURNAME', 'AGE', 'ID']
lst2 = [['NAME', 'JOHN'], ['SURNAME', 'SMITH'], ['ACTIVE', 'Y'], ['ID_', '33']]
lst3 = []

for i in lst1:
    for j in lst2:
        if i == j[0] or i + '_' == j[0]:
            lst3.append(j)

print(lst3)
```